# How to write a json file in c

Tags: c, json

I need to create a `json` file containing this data using `c`. How do i proceed? Thanks!

```
{
"key" : "asdf",
"mapregister" :
  {
  "proxyMapReply" : true,
  "eidToLocatorRecords" :
    [
      {
      "authoritative" : true,
      "prefixGeneric" :
        {
        "ipAddress" : "2.2.2.2",
        "afi" : 1
        },
      "mapVersion" : 0,
      "maskLength" : 32,
      "action" : "NoAction",
      "locators" :
        [
          {
          "multicastPriority" : 1,
          "locatorGeneric" :
            {
            "ipAddress" : "10.33.12.37",
            "afi" : 1
            },
          "routed" : true,
          "multicastWeight" : 0,
          "rlocProbed" : false,
          "localLocator" : false,
          "priority" : 126,
          "weight" : 1
          } ,
          {
          "multicastPriority" : 1,
          "locatorGeneric" :
            {
            "ipAddress" : "10.33.12.44",
            "afi" : 1
            },
          "routed" : true,
          "multicastWeight" : 0,
          "rlocProbed" : false,
          "localLocator" : false,
          "priority" : 127,
          "weight" : 1
          }
        ],
      "recordTtl" : 5
      }
    ],
  "keyId" : 0
  }
}
```

Comment: go to http://json.org/ scroll down, pick a c json library and start learning/using it. Or put the string together by yourself, maybe using a templating technique, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own logic to build JSON files and parse JSON files. But i suggest you to use any 3rd party library for the same.

Check it out http://www.json.org/

It has all basic of JSON files and provide list of projects/tools available for JSON parser and creater in different programming list.

---

For **c programming** i suggest you to use https://github.com/json-c/json-c/wiki

Comment: ok, ill try your method. But how dows it all go together? In the sense, once i install the json-c code then what? do i just use it as a library in my main code?

Comment: you need to use it as library. and you can use it by static linking so here your execuatable has code of library...if dynamic linking is used then where ever you run your executable you need to install this json library...

Comment: ok, cool. i found this example https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/json_object_new_object/, so i guess ill start from here. thanks again!

Comment: Thanks in Stackoverflow is Upvote/accepting answer :)...anyway welcome buddy

Comment: will do as soon i get it working and running :)